# Вопрос про reсycle_view

Tags: java, android

Как сделать список, в элементе recycle view. То есть каждый элемент в списке, может содержать ещё один под список? Думал через inflater сделать, но пока не получается

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Список в списке можно сделать и без использования RV. Есть такая штука - ExpandableListView и в нем может быть список в списке. Для этого добавляем в xml виджет:

```
 <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

переходим в активность и заполняем его:

```
Map<String, String> map;
// коллекция для групп
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupDataList = new ArrayList<>();
// заполняем коллекцию групп из массива с названиями групп

for (String group : mGroupsArray) {
            // заполняем список атрибутов для каждой группы
            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("groupName", group); // время года
            groupDataList.add(map);
}

// список атрибутов групп для чтения
String groupFrom[] = new String[] { "groupName" };
// список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты групп
int groupTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

// создаем общую коллекцию для коллекций элементов
ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> сhildDataList = new ArrayList<>();

// в итоге получится сhildDataList = ArrayList<сhildDataItemList>

// создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
// заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
for (String month : mWinterMonthsArray) {
map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("monthName", month); // название месяца
сhildDataItemList.add(map);
}
// добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);

// создаем коллекцию элементов для второй группы
сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String month : mSpringMonthsArray) {
   map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("monthName", month);
   сhildDataItemList.add(map);
}
сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);

// создаем коллекцию элементов для третьей группы
сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String month : mSummerMonthsArray) {
map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("monthName", month);
сhildDataItemList.add(map);
}
сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);

// создаем коллекцию элементов для четвертой группы
сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String month : mAutumnMonthsArray) {
            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("monthName", month);
            сhildDataItemList.add(map);
}
сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);

// список атрибутов элементов для чтения
String childFrom[] = new String[] { "monthName" };
// список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты
// элементов
int childTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
      this, groupDataList,
      android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
      groupTo, сhildDataList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
      childFrom, childTo);

ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);
expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

вот тут [первоисточник-туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/expandablelistview.php) и хорошие туториалы [1](https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial) и [2](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/). Если все-таки вам нужно сделать на базе RV то придется делать адаптер где в качестве элемента будет использоваться разметка со списком. В каждый элемент главного списка будет использовать другой адаптер где внутренние списки будут заполняться тоже данными. На мой взгляд проще сделать через expandable list view. Но если есть необходимость делать через RV то дайте знать, я где-то такой примерчик видел, поищу.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать примерчик как реализовать это с RV?

Answer (score 0):

У вас должно быть два адаптера. Для основного списка и для раскрывающегося при нажатии.

**ExpandableAdapter:**

```
class ExpandableAdapter(
items: List<Item>,
private val nestedClickListener: (String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandableAdapter.ExpandableViewHolder>() {

val items = mutableListOf<Item>()

init {
    this.items.addAll(items)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ExpandableViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
)

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExpandableViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]

    with(holder) {
        text.text = item.text
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            list.visibility = VISIBLE
            list.adapter = NestedAdapter(item.nestedItems) { nestedClickListener(it) }
        }
    }
}

class ExpandableViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val text: TextView = view.text
    val list: RecyclerView = view.recycler
}
}
```

**NestedAdapter:**

```
class NestedAdapter(
items: List<String>,
private val clickListener: (String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NestedAdapter.NestedViewHolder>() {

val items = mutableListOf<String>()

init {
    this.items.addAll(items)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = NestedViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
)

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NestedViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]

    with(holder) {
        text.text = item
        itemView.setOnClickListener { clickListener(item) }
    }
}

class NestedViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val text: TextView = view.text
}
}
```

При нажатии на элемент списка вы делаете вложенный список видимым и создаете вложенный адаптер.